# Can I automatically apply traits to my starting pawns?

Tags: rimworld

As many rimworld players know, the traits Bloodlust, Psychopath, and cannibal are some of the most overpowered traits in the game. They can provide many benefits to the colony, especially to morale.

As a result of this I want to add these traits to all my colonists. Unfortunately, it’s quite annoying to press randomize thousands of time to get a decent colonist with those traits.

How can I automatically add these traits to a colonist?

Comment: are you ok with mods? Because the only way to achieve this is with mods, iirc. That said, I haven't played the game in a long while so this may have changed, that's why I didn't answer with this.

Comment: @Rapitor A mod is an acceptable answer, but since it wouldn’t work on the console version it’s probably not the best answer. That said, it’s just as possible that any other answer wouldn’t work on console, I don’t know what differences there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 3 different ways to do it:

- The legit and most fun way to do it is without changing traits, by using the Ideology DLC. Then you can create an ideology/religion and adjust it's attitude to cannibalism, harvesting or whatever other evil deeds you like to play with. If your ideology favours cannibalism, you won't get any mood drops from followers of that religion when someone in the colony practices cannibalism.
- There are also mods like "prepare carefully" or some such which lets you customize colonists much more conveniently than endless re-rolling. Been a long while since I used that mod so I'm not sure of the exact name or if it's up to date - there's several mods like that though.
- If you enter the debug mode, basically an in-game cheat system, you can reset and set traits of all colonists and do a ton of other stuff. In options, click "Development mode". Now a bunch of icons will pop up at the top of your screen. Click the 4th one from the left "open debug actions menu", then find the options "give trait" or "remove all traits". I think you need to launch the colony before you can use these.

  Once done tweaking, you probably want to disable development mode in the menu once more, or otherwise you'll get all manner of annoying debug message pop-ups meant for the programmers/modders.

Comment: +1, didn’t know that much about the ideology dlc but if it lets me commit war crimes (in game, if I need to specify) with lessened debuffs I might look into getting it.

Comment: @Topcode It's possible to use it to create for example a raider faction ideology which -expects- you to hit other camps at regular basis, Or to create a nudist cannibal tribe or whatever :) I'm currently playing as a faction of runaway androids (mod) who's gone hippie and just want to farm weed in peace :)

Comment: Sounds like it’s worth getting, and you can convert people to your ideology right? So it’s better than just starting with a bunch of bloodthirsty psychopaths

Comment: @Topcode Yes you need to covert all recruits to the colony or they'll stick to their previous ideology based on which faction they previously belonged to.